# Allow access to printer between interfaces on Cisco ASA5510

Tags: firewall, routing, cisco-asa

I have a Cisco ASA5510 where we have to separate networks on two separate interfaces.

The networks should have nothing to do with each other except that network B needs to access a printer on network A.

```
Network A: 192.168.137.0/24
Printer: 192.168.137.20 
Network B: 192.168.0.0/24
```

I've added an incoming rule from Network A to the Printer IP in the ASDM interface but clients can't print.

Our previous router was configured to let traffic through so the clients on Network B is already configured so it think it *should* work if traffic is allowed.

How do I let clients on Network B communicate with the printer?

**UPDATE:**

Found the following inte the firewall log (thanks to resmon6):

> %ASA-5-305013: Asymmetric NAT rules matched for forward and reverse 
>   flows; Connection protocol src
>   interface_name:source_address/source_port [(idfw_user)] dst
>   interface_name:dst_address/dst_port [(idfw_user)] denied due to  NAT
>   reverse path failure. An attempt to connect to a mapped host using its
>   actual address was rejected.

I'm new to ASA so please bear with me, I guess i should add a NAT rule in the `Configuration`> `Firewall` > `NAT Rules` but what settings should it have to allow only the printer to be translated?

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the current NAT-rules:

```
Result of the command: "show run nat"

nat (NetworkA) 101 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
nat (NetworkB) 101 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
nat (NetworkC) 101 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0



Result of the command: "show run global"

global (outside) 101 interface



Result of the command: "show run static"

The command has been sent to the device
```

Comment: These are all private networks... why do you need NAT on these sources to begin with?  Are there problems with overlapping address space, or a need to identify traffic with a specific IP address?

Comment: I'm not sure if I need it, i thought so since the firewall said there was a NAT issue. All I need is to be able to access the printer from Network B.

Comment: Jonas, did you put NAT on the FW, or was it there when you started working on the problem?  If the former, then remove NAT.  If the latter, then find the person who put it there and figure out what it's there for.

Comment: It was already there. I'll try to contact the one who put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the firewall logs when you are trying to print to the server to see if you're missing any ACL rules. A good way to do this is in ASDM under the <kbd>monitoring</kbd>=><kbd>logging</kbd> sections.

edit:
You need to add a static NAT translation from NetworkA to NetworkB for that printer. The CLI command for this would be `static (NetworkA,NetworkB) 192.168.137.20 192.168.137.20 netmask 255.255.255.255`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with the results. It seems to be a NAT issue.

Comment: Can you post your nat configuration?

Comment: Yes, how do I export it i a readable format?

Comment: login through the command line and do a `show run nat`, `show run global` and `show run static`. You can do this from ASDM using the Tools>Command Line Interface menu.

Comment: You need to add a static NAT translation from NetworkA to NetworkB for that printer. The CLI command for this would be `static (NetworkA,NetworkB) 192.168.137.20 192.168.137.20 netmask 255.255.255.255`